# SDWebImage is crashing while loading the image - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',

Tags: ios, crash, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage library to load images to uitableview. Please see the code for loading below. But when i run from device it is crashing occasionally stating that "**Terminating app due to uncaught exception** '**NSInternalInconsistencyException**' "

```
    NSString *gTableIdentifier = @"GTableCell";

    GTableCell *cell = (GTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:gTableIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        //Selection Color
        UIView *selectionView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        [selectionView setBackgroundColor:TABLE_SELECTION_COLOR];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionView;
        [cell.thumbnailImageView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
        [cell.thumbnailImageView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    }

    cell.headline.text = [ShContentManager GetHeadLinesTitle:[indexPath row]];
    cell.headLineSource.text = [ShContentManager GetHeadLinesTitleSource:[indexPath row]];

    NSString *imageURL = [ShContentManager GetHeadLinesImageURL:[indexPath row]];

    if(imageURL != NULL)
    {

        [cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
                                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.thumbnailImageView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
        [cell.thumbnailImageView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple-touch-icon-iphone.png"];
    }
```

Below is the error details

```
2013-05-07 20:46:35.732 TopStory[35529:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '{ Rows:
GTableCell:0x1cdca0d0.Height == 180 + 1*0x1d8b4830.marker
GTableCell:0x1cdca0d0.Width == 640 + 1*0x1d8b46a0.marker
GTableCell:0x1cdca0d0.minX == 0 + 1*0x1d8b3810.marker + -0.5*0x1d8b46a0.marker
GTableCell:0x1cdca0d0.minY == 360 + 1*0x1d8b44b0.marker + -0.5*0x1d8b4830.marker
UILabel:0x1cdca210.minX == 166 + -1*0x1cdca680.marker + 1*0x1cdca6c0.marker + -1*0x1cdca700.marker + 1*UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.minX
UILabel:0x1cdca210.minY == 0 + -1*0x1cdca640.marker + 1*UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.Height + 1*UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.minY + -1*UILabel:0x1cdca210.Height
UILabel:0x1d896e50.minX == 166 + -1*0x1cdca680.marker + 1*0x1cdca6c0.marker + -1*0x1cdca700.marker + 1*0x1cdca740.marker + 1*UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.minX + 1*UILabel:0x1cdca210.Width + -1*UILabel:0x1d896e50.Width
UILabel:0x1d896e50.minY == -0 + -1*0x1cdca5c0.marker + 1*0x1cdca780.marker + 1*UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.minY
UILabel:0x1d8d56b0.minX == 166 + -1*0x1cdca680.marker + 1*0x1cdca6c0.marker + 1*UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.minX
UILabel:0x1d8d56b0.minY == 0 + -1*0x1cdca5c0.marker + 1*UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.minY
UITableViewCellContentView:0x1cdc9af0.minX == 12 + 1*0x1cdca680.marker + -1*UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.minX
UITableViewCellContentView:0x1cdc9af0.minY == 90 + 1*0x1cdca600.marker + 0.5*0x1d8b4830.marker + -0.5*UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.Height + -1*UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.minY
objective == <> + <750:-1>*0x1d8b0b60.negError + <250:-1>*0x1d8b0b60.posErrorMarker + <750:-1>*0x1d8b0c30.negError + <250:-1>*0x1d8b0c30.posErrorMarker
```

Constraints:

```
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1d8b3810 h=--- v=--- GTableCell:0x1cdca0d0.midX == + 320>     Marker:0x1d8b3810.marker
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1d8b44b0 h=--- v=--- GTableCell:0x1cdca0d0.midY == + 450>     Marker:0x1d8b44b0.marker
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x1d8b0b60 H:[UIImageView:0x1d896ee0(80)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>     Marker:0x1d8b0b60.posErrorMarker
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x1d8b0c30 V:[UIImageView:0x1d896ee0(60)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>     Marker:0x1d8b0c30.posErrorMarker
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1cdca5c0 UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.top == UILabel:0x1d8d56b0.top>        Marker:0x1cdca5c0.marker
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1cdca600 UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.centerY == GTableCell:0x1cdca0d0.centerY>     Marker:0x1cdca600.marker
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1cdca640 UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.bottom == UILabel:0x1cdca210.bottom>      Marker:0x1cdca640.marker
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1cdca680 UIImageView:0x1d896ee0.leading == GTableCell:0x1cdca0d0.leading + 6>     Marker:0x1cdca680.marker
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1cdca6c0 UILabel:0x1d8d56b0.leading == GTableCell:0x1cdca0d0.leading + 89>        Marker:0x1cdca6c0.marker
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1cdca700 UILabel:0x1d8d56b0.leading == UILabel:0x1cdca210.leading>        Marker:0x1cdca700.marker
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1cdca740 UILabel:0x1d896e50.trailing == UILabel:0x1cdca210.trailing>      Marker:0x1cdca740.marker
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1cdca780 UILabel:0x1d896e50.top == UILabel:0x1d8d56b0.top>        Marker:0x1cdca780.marker
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d8b46a0 H:[GTableCell:0x1cdca0d0(640)]>      Marker:0x1d8b46a0.marker
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d8b4830 V:[GTableCell:0x1cdca0d0(180)]>      Marker:0x1d8b4830.marker


}: internal error.  Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head 0x1d8b0b60.negError, which should never happen.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x324ea2a3 0x3a21297f 0x324ea1c5 0x32e9c11f 0x32e9e759 0x32e9e8af 0x3472bc4f 0x34308451 0x34306f39 0x11352d 0x10f7f9 0x10aa91 0x3a62a11f 0x3a6294b7 0x3a62e1bd 0x324bdf3b 0x32430ebd 0x32430d49 0x360092eb 0x34346301 0xd74bd 0x3a649b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```